# Does LDAP support SAML 2.0 requests?

Tags: saml-2.0, openldap

I am working on a project where we are planning to use SAML 2.0 to send authentication requests to OpenLDAP. Can someone please tell me if its supported or not? I am not able to get the clear answer via Google.

Answer (score 2):

SAML and LDAP are completely different things. SAML is mostly used for Web-based SSO. The identity provider (IdP) part of the access manager software/system you're using (i.e., the one that implements SAML authentication authority) may use a back-end LDAP server (e.g., OpenLDAP) for authenticating users.